# Struggling to translate "iuvenum" in a sentence

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, sentence-translation

I'm struggling with the translation of the following sentence:

> Praeterea quinque milia iuvenum iussu principis magna voce plaudere debebant.

It is not clear to me what to do with the word *iuvenum*, that I think would be "young" here. I believe it is Gen.Pl. but neither the *milia* nor *principis* agree with that. The *milia*, as far as I can tell, are in Nom. and the *principis* is singular. So I don't know who/what should be "young" here?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Shouldn't *princips* be *principis*? Looks like a typo.

Comment: Yes, this was a typo! changed it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is all about how thousands work in Latin.
The singular *mille* is an undeclinable adjective, the plural *milia* is a third declension noun.
When you are counting the youth, with *mille* the young are in whatever case you need and with *milia* it is *milia* that is in the correct grammatical case and the young are in the genitive.
In the singular the number is the attribute of the noun, in the plural the noun is the attribute of the number.

In your sentence nothing agrees with *iuvenum*.
The word *iuvenum* is a genitive attribute of *quinque milia*.

In a table:

| Case | One thousand young people | Two thousand young people |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nom. | *mille iuvenes* | *duo milia iuvenum* |
| Acc. | *mille iuvenes* | *duo milia iuvenum* |
| Gen. | *mille iuvenum* | *duorum milium iuvenum* |
| Dat. | *mille iuvenibus* | *duobus milibus iuvenum* |
| Abl. | *mille iuvenibus* | *duobus milibus iuvenum* |

Comment: Nice succinct summary, +1 for you